# bundle not found when running services using upstart/foreman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rbenv, foreman

I'm setting up a staging environment for a Rails 4 app on Ubuntu 12.04.
I use:
 - rbenv for managing rubies
 - capistrano for deployemnt
 - foreman for managing services

In particular, I want to run que as a service. My Procfile looks like

```
que: bundle exec rake que:work
```

I have exported the Procfile for upstart successfully. My sapp-que-1.conf looks like

```
start on starting ft-id-que
stop on stopping ft-id-que
respawn

exec su - deployer -c 'cd /home/deployer/apps/sapp/releases/20140307080502; export PORT=5000; bundle exec rake que:work  >> /home/deployer/apps/sapp/current/log/que-1.log 2>&1'
```

When I try to start it (`sudo start sapp`) I get the following error:

`-su: bundle: command not found`

However if I cd into /home/deployer/apps/sapp/releases/20140307080502 and I manually run `bundle exec rake que:work` the rake is executed.

Am I missing anything here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Could you have `.bash_profile` ?

The `su` does not read `.bashrc`.

[[SOLVED] Special user, .bashrc not being executed upon login](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1868728)

I create `.bash_profile` with

```
# Load the default .profile
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" 

# Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```